# Does firebug (and Chrome's network monitor) monitor a java applet's http POSTs/GETs?

Tags: java, applet, firebug, monitor

Does firebug (and Chrome's network monitor) monitor a java applet's http posts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it doesn't...
I use Fiddler instead...